# One column in a join needs to be unique

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer, window-functions

I am new to SQL. I have a join which uses three lookup tables. It is a bit complicated so I will publish the code here.

```
Create View TEST As select  
        BDP_INSTITUTION_NAME,
        BIC,
        BDP_COUNTRY_NAME,               
        BDP_ISO_COUNTRY_CODE,            
        BDP_CITY,                       
        BDP_NETWORK_CONNECTIVITY,      
        BDP_SERVICE_CODES,               
        BDP_ISTARGET,                        
        BCDB_NAME,                       
        BCDB_LAENDERKENNZEICHEN,  
        BCDB_AKTIVMERKMALBANK,          
        BCDB_AKTIVMERKMALLAND,     
        BCDB_AKTIVMERKMALBANKLAND, 
        BCDB_SWIFTKENNZEICHEN,    
        COUNTRYCODE,     
        ISBDP,    
        ISBCDB,    
        BCDB_ORT,
        RMA.CRSPDT AS RMA_CRSPDT,
        RMA.ISSR AS RMA_ISSR,
        RMA.TP AS RMA_TP,
        RMA.SVCNM AS RMA_SVCNM,
        RMA.RMASTS AS RMA_RMASTS 
       from
(SELECT 
        bdp.bic, 
        bdp.institution_name AS bdp_institution_name, 
        bdp.country_name AS bdp_country_name, 
        bdp.iso_country_code AS bdp_iso_country_code,
        bdp.city AS bdp_city, 
        bdp.network_connectivity AS bdp_network_connectivity, 
        bdp.service_codes as bdp_service_codes, 
        bdp.isTarget AS bdp_isTarget, 
        bcdb.name as bcdb_name, 
        bcdb.laenderKennzeichen as bcdb_laenderKennzeichen, 
        bcdb.aktivMerkmalBank AS bcdb_aktivMerkmalBank, 
        bcdb.aktivMerkmalLand AS bcdb_aktivMerkmalLand, 
        bcdb.aktivMerkmalBankLand AS bcdb_aktivMerkmalBankLand, 
        bcdb.swiftKennzeichen AS bcdb_swiftKennzeichen, 
        CASE 
            WHEN bcdb.laenderKennzeichen IS NOT NULL THEN bcdb.laenderKennzeichen
            ELSE bdp.iso_country_code
        END AS countryCode,
        CASE 
            WHEN bdp.bic IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS isbdp,
        CASE 
            WHEN bcdb.bic IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS isbcdb,
        bcdb.ort AS bcdb_ort 
        FROM BDP bdp LEFT JOIN BCDB bcdb ON bdp.bic = bcdb.bic WHERE bdp.bic IS NOT NULL 
    UNION ALL SELECT
        bcdb.bic, 
        bdp.institution_name AS bdp_institution_name, 
        bdp.country_name AS bdp_country_name, 
        bdp.iso_country_code AS bdp_iso_country_code, 
        bdp.city AS bdp_city, 
        bdp.network_connectivity AS bdp_network_connectivity, 
        bdp.service_codes as bdp_service_codes,
        bdp.isTarget AS bdp_isTarget, 
        bcdb.name as bcdb_name, 
        bcdb.laenderKennzeichen as bcdb_laenderKennzeichen, 
        bcdb.aktivMerkmalBank AS bcdb_aktivMerkmalBank, 
        bcdb.aktivMerkmalLand AS bcdb_aktivMerkmalLand, 
        bcdb.aktivMerkmalBankLand AS bcdb_aktivMerkmalBankLand, 
        bcdb.swiftKennzeichen AS bcdb_swiftKennzeichen, 
        CASE 
            WHEN bcdb.laenderKennzeichen IS NOT NULL THEN bcdb.laenderKennzeichen
            ELSE bdp.iso_country_code
        END AS countryCode,
        CASE 
            WHEN bdp.bic IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS isbdp,
        CASE 
            WHEN bcdb.bic IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS isbcdb,
        bcdb.ort AS bcdb_ort 
    FROM BDP bdp RIGHT JOIN BCDB bcdb ON bdp.bic = bcdb.bic WHERE bdp.bic IS NULL)

  t1 left join RMA on (RMA.ISSR = substr(t1.BIC, 1,8) or RMA.CRSPDT = substr(t1.BIC, 1,8));
```

What I want is to have a unique BIC for each row in the 'TEST' view. The rest of the information is not important i.e. once I get a hit on a BIC it should not be repeated again, all the rest is not important what is important is if I get a BIC hit or not.

Through internet search I found out I cannot use DISTINCT in my case it does not help. What else can I do?

Comment: Is there any particular order? IE: Any particular data you'd want to show for a given BIC?

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ From the RMA directory there is nothing in particular only that either RMA.ISSR or RMA.CRSPDT have a 'hit' with the BIC.

Comment: Something like this?   `select c.* from (select b.*, row_number() over(partition by b.bic order by b.rnum) rnk from (select rownum rnum, a.* from test a) b) c where rnk = 1;` ?

Comment: @Raj I have however run into a problem. There are two environments I am to run my code in Production and Development. In the production environment we use Oracle so your given command works however in the development environment we use Derby and the "partition by" command seems to throw an error.

Comment: @supervisor - you will run into these issues all the time when developing against a different database to your Live environment. I assume non-technical people thought this was a good idea to save money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work (in Oracle).

```
select c.* from (select b.*, row_number() over(partition by b.bic order by b.rnum) rnk from (select rownum rnum, a.* from test a) b) c where rnk = 1;
```